# passing javascript variable to ng-click event in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to pass Javascript variables to `ng-click` event in angular js but am getting null values.

Below is my javascript variables that needs to be passed to angular js

```
<script>

var userid = localStorage.getItem("userid");
var uName = localStorage.getItem("name");
var uage = localStorage.getItem("age");


<script>
```

Below is my angular js controller

```
<script>
app1 = angular.module('app1');

        app1.controller('mainCtrl',
                ['$scope', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $rootScope) {

               console.log("Data okay");

                    }]);

<script>
```

Here is how am passing the variables to `NG-CLICK` events

```
<li ng-show=" ap in parkers | filter:{ name: uname } " id="userid"  ng-click="connect(userid,uname,uage)">
</li>
```

How can I accomplished that and ensure it will be working. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variables need to be attached to the controller's `$scope`. Delete your variables and add `$scope` variables like below:

```
app1.controller('mainCtrl',
        ['$scope', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $rootScope) {

       console.log("Data okay");
       $scope.userid = localStorage.getItem("userid");
       $scope.uName = localStorage.getItem("name");
       $scope.uage = localStorage.getItem("age");
       $scope.connect = function(userId, uName, uAge){
           console.log('It worked!'); 
       }

}]);
```

Note that the `connect` function also needs to be attached to the `$scope` to be called via `ng-click`.

Comment: Just an addition:The difference here is `$scope` (named for obvious reason) scopes the value to the controller it is defined in, and binds that value to the view. `var` will not bind to template views, so it's not accessible in `ng-click/show` etc

Comment: Agree with all that 100%